# Character limiting with javascript won't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this piece of JavaScript from way back in time:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function limiter(txtMsg, CharLength, indicator)
    {
        chars = txtMsg.value.length;
        document.getElementById(indicator).innerHTML = CharLength - chars;
        if (chars > CharLength)
        {
            txtMsg.value = txtMsg.value.substring(0, CharLength);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

And I then have a textarea in which to limit the number of characters
and it's called like this:

```
<textarea name="tbUnit" rows="2" cols="20" id="tbUnit" class="inpText" onkeyup="limiter(this,50,'lblunitCount')" style="height:51px;width:350px;"></textarea>
```

and

```
<span id="unitCount">50</span>
```

This works fine in Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari and IE 10 and 11. However in IE 9 on Windows 7 the textarea is limited to 1 character no matter what I try.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious if wrapping everything in `limiter` in a `setTimeout` will fix this. I wonder if the `onkeyup` event is lagging a bit. You can also set a breakpoint to see if `txtMsg` looks like how you expect.

Comment: What is the output of `chars ` variable at any given moment in IE9 console?

Comment: I just ran it in debug mode and it seems to play nice. It doesn't fire the  txtMsg.value = txtMsg.value.substring(0, CharLength); in order to block anything. I input exactly one char and chars are then, as expected, 1 and CharLength is 50 and the statement if(chars > charLength) ends up as false. But still it locks the textarea.

Comment: This is not a solution, but for all modern browsers you should use the attribute `maxlength`.  As in, `<textarea maxlength=50></textarea>`, no javascript needed.  That will do it for modern browsers.  But if you really need to support IE9, this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I found the error, thank you all for your help.
The issues were a bug in the jquery.autotab library that for some reason Went haywire on IE9 in Windows 7.